# Unexpected assignment within a 'do...while' statement. Why is this bad practice and what can I do instead?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, eslint

I am getting an eslint error:
[eslint] Unexpected assignment within a 'do...while' statement. (no-cond-assign)

Why is this happening?
What can I do to fix it?
Why am I not allowed to do this? Why is this bad practice?

```
window.smoothScroll = function (target) {
    let scrollContainer = target;
    do {
        scrollContainer = scrollContainer.parentNode;
        if (!scrollContainer) return;
        scrollContainer.scrollTop += 1;
    } while (scrollContainer.scrollTop === 0);

    let targetY = 0;
    do {
        if (target === scrollContainer) break;
        targetY += target.offsetTop;
    } while (target = target.offsetParent);

    const scroll = (c, a, b, i) => {
        i += 1; if (i > 30) return;
        c.scrollTop = (((a + (b - a)) / 30) * i);
        setTimeout(() => { scroll(c, a, b, i); }, 10);
    };
    scroll(scrollContainer, scrollContainer.scrollTop, targetY, 0);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

`while` expects an *expression*, whereas `target = target.offsetParent` is an *assignment*. While assignment does *evaluate* to an expression, *very often* its use is either a bug or a code smell. For example, as the linter explains:

```
if (user.jobTitle = "manager") {
```

The above code is *almost certainly* a typo. If you want to assign to a variable, it's best to do it on a standalone line, rather than in an expression, to make your code clear to future readers (including yourself).

In your code, you could fix it by assigning to `target` in the bottom of the `do`, and then put just `target` in the `while` condition:

```
do {
  if (target === scrollContainer) break;
  targetY += target.offsetTop;
  target = target.offsetParent
} while (target);
```

Comment: Might be worth noting *sometimes* you can use assignment in a `while` as a shorthand. For example, you are interested in the next zero, while ignoring other input `while (myVar = someIntegerGenerator.next())` as a `do...while` you could process all non-zero outputs and stop when you reach zero. However, in my experience this construct is quite rarely needed. It could also be confusing if you're glancing over it - it's usually accompanied with a comment - in the style of self-documenting code, you could just pull the assignment in the body.